# Button inside table row tr, when clicking button only do button action

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to have a button inside a row.

when clicking the button I want it to do A.

and when clicking the row I want it to do B.

I tried to stop propagation, and at one point it was working, but I don't know what I didn't and I can't manage to make it work again.

Probably there is a better way to do this.

I have a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/YJ6eG/

```
function stopEvent(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
  alert("event propagation halted.");
}
function stopPropagation(elem) {
  elem = document.getElementById("row1");
  elem.addEventListener("click", stopEvent, true);
}
```

Comment: check my answer out and let me know if you had any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your code like this:

```
<table id="ID_to_Stop">
    <tr id="row1" onclick="alert('row 1 clicked');">
        <td id="c12">this is row 1, if you click it, it should do something
            <button id="btn1">and if you click me I should do something different</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" onclick="alert('row 2 clicked');">
        <td id="c22">this is row 2
            <button id="btn2">click me</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the js part:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

btn1.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
    alert('btn 1 clicked');
    ev.stopPropagation();
}, true);

btn2.addEventListener("click", function (ev) {
    alert('btn 2 clicked');
    ev.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

And this is your updated [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ6eG/6/).

Comment: thanks a lot, Mehran, it works perfectly. Just one question what is the "ev." in front of "stopPropagation();" for? I got this from another code.

Comment: whenever an event is triggered, browser creates an Event object to let you have all the information you need regarding that event, for instance if you have a click event as far as it is related to the Mouse, browser creates a MouseEvent which has all the information about the triggered event, the position, actual target DOM element and etc. `ev` here is a MouseEvent with all related info about the actual click on your html element.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working although.And if it is working in some case, it will allow only single click as you killed the event on row **row1** .Use below given code to get desired result.

---

HTML:-

---

```
<table id="ID_to_Stop">
<tr id="row1" onclick="alert('row 1 clicked');">
    <td id="c12">this is row 1, if you click it, it should do something
        <button id="btn1" onclick="btn1Call(event);">and if you click me I should do something different</button>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="row2" onclick="alert('row 2 clicked');">
    <td id="c22">this is row 2
        <button id="btn2" onclick="btn2Call(event);">click me</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

javascript : -

---

```
<script>

function btn1Call(e) {
    alert('btn 1 clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
}

function btn2Call(e) {
    alert('btn 2 clicked');
    e.stopPropagation();
}
</script>
```